# Автоматизация создания определений конструкторов классов из их определения внутри .h

Tags: автоматизация, visual-studio, c++, макрос

Есть .h файл в нем определены ~90 классов. Классы вложены(nested class) друг в друга до 3 раз. Нужно для каждого класса создать определения конструкторов/деструкторов в .cpp файле. Это реально сделать через какой-нибудь пункт меню/плагин в Visual Studio или иным простым способом не вбивая все это вручную?

Нужны примерно такие определения:

```
 UI::AchivementsLayout::AchivementsBackToMainMenuButton::AchivementsBackToMainMenuButton()
{
    x=0.0f;
    y=0.0f
}
```

Comment: - Если уже есть определения конструкторов, то делаете в `Visual Assist X` [**Create Implementation**][1] для каждого конструктора.

- Можете придумать регексп для конструкторов / деструкторов и перемещаться по ним по `F3.`

- *Китайский код - не труъ.* Зачем вам потребовалось столько конструкторов?

[1]: http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/createImplementation.asp

Comment: Да тут похоже такой случай, что может вполне помочь. Нужно сделать с нуля кросс-платформенный интерфейс для игры, отрисовывающийся через OpenGL без использования сторонних библиотек или шаблонов. Я думал сначала просто написать небольшую библиотеку стандартных UI элементов вроде кнопок/рамок/полос прокрутки и потом через нее определить нужные мне окна, но потом решил что писать библиотеку ради отрисовки 10 побочных окон в одном проекте не очень здравая идея и просто сделал один китайский класс UI.

Comment: О да эта штуковина сработала как нужно. Минут 40 времени сэкономила.

Answer (score 1):

*Из комментария пользователя [@CostantinoRupert](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4149/costantino-rupert):*

1. Если уже есть определения конструкторов, то делаете в *Visual Assist X* [`Create Implementation`](http://wholetomato.com/products/features/createImplementation.asp)<sup>[[архив](https://web.archive.org/web/20160712223646/http://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W163)]</sup> для каждого конструктора.
2. Можете придумать регексп для конструкторов / деструкторов и перемещаться по ним по <kbd>F3</kbd>.
3. Китайский код — не труъ. Зачем вам потребовалось столько конструкторов?